# Webpack save images location

Tags: webpack

I am following the webpack tutorial on importing images by code, which makes webpack include the image in the distributed project. Perhaps I'm missing something but in my case all images are dumped in the root project directory instead of in an images folder.

The only answers I've found look like this, but this seems to be for webpack 1?

```
test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
loader: 'file-loader?limit=100000&name=./imgs/[hash].[ext]'
```

If I try this webpack config

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/js/app.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'js/bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          'file-loader?limit=100000&name=./imgs/[hash].[ext]'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

I get this error:

```
 Can't resolve 'file-loader&name=images/[name].[ext]
```

How can I define the destination for images in webpack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My dist folder is up 2 levels from my webpack.config.js. Here's what my fonts and image setup is. I'm using Webpack 3.x.

```
{
  test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
   use: {
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      name: 'public/images/[name].[hash].[ext]',
      publicPath: '../../'
    }
  }
},
{
  test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
  use: {
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      name: 'public/fonts/[name].[hash].[ext]',
      publicPath: '../../'
     }
   }
 }
```